# why can't I open a windows azure media services account in north america?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Does anyone know why the only region options for creating a Windows Azure Media Services are: Southeast Asia; East Asia; Japan West?  I am in the US and would like to pick the region I am in.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a support ticket to enable additional regions.